# Чтение из массива java

Tags: java, массивы, строки, split

Есть программа, которая разбивает введенное предложение сплитом  на слова и записывает в массив.

```
words = textField.getText();

String[] split = words.split(" ?(?<!\\G)((?<=[^\\p{Punct}])(?=\\p{Punct})|\\b) ?");
Arrays.stream(split).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Далее из массива нужно достать каждое слово отдельно и присвоить переменную, но подозреваю, что делаю я это неправильно, т.к. IDE выдает вместо слов

> `[Ljava.lang.String;@3050b752`.

Код вывода:

```
messege = " <" + "split" + " = " + random + "> ";
System.out.println(messege);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить задачу?

Comment: А как нижний код связан с верхним? `System.out.println` есть и там, и там. Представленный вывод - он откуда? Плюс было бы здорово вместо `words = textField.getText();` привести пример конкретного массива, например: `String[] words = { "a", "b" };`. И что такое `random`?

Comment: И не по вопросу: таки `message`, а не `messege`

Comment: `System.out.println`  в верхнем коде был больше для контроля правильности работы сплита . Представленный вывод - это то , что выводит IDE в консоли (в messege) . Если я правильно понял, то строчкой `Arrays.stream(split)` в массив записывается содержание сплита. random - это переменная , в которой написано : `int random = (int) (Math.random() * 999999999);` . За "message" спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String words = textField.getText();

String[] split = words.split(" ?(?<!\\G)((?<=[^\\p{Punct}])(?=\\p{Punct})|\\b) ?");
for (String s : split ) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)):

```java
String[] split = ...

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Вывод:

```
[word1, word2, word3, ...]
```